# Angle of wedge buffer not rendering on one point

Tags: qgis, style, expression, geometry-generator, temporal-controller

I have been making pie charts with wedge buffers in QGIS for temporal controller. I just bumped into an issue with one point which completely ignores the azimuth angle for one color. The formula for the blue wedge in geometry generator is

```
wedge_buffer(
    center:=$geometry,
    azimuth:=("Green"*360/"Total")+("Red"*360/"Total")+("Yellow"*360/"Total")+("Orange"*180/"Total")+("Blue"*180/"Total"),
    width:=("Blue"*360)/"Total",
    outer_radius:=2*log10("Total")
)
```

This works for all points except for one

[image]

[image]

It's ignoring the calculated azimuth value of 135 and settling down at zero. Inputting numbers for azimuth sometimes puts the blue wedge for the highlighted point in the wrong location. Azimuth=135 does not put the wedge where it should be at 135, but other values like 90 degrees are correct. What could be causing this problem? Is QGIS misreading the numbers? I have tried reloading the layer.
The data for this point is

| Orange | Yellow | Red | Green | Blue | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

Comment: Since we're not that deep into your project: How do you expect the buffer to look like?

Comment: I expect complete circles in the end. The blue section on that one point should be a semicircle on the top half. After restarting, the blue section appears in the correct spot but disappears depending on the zoom. Can I change that in the settings?

Comment: the only workaround I found for when opening and closing QGIS doesn't work is to add .001 to the azimuth